# laravel 5.3 image upload file path store in variable

Tags: object, image-uploading, laravel-5.3

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File Object ( [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => employee\logo_5781432114142.jpg [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => logo_5781432114142.jpg ) 
I want to store path-Name in a variable How would I store the file path

Answer (score 0):

tried an alternate way to store image file path 
example:-  $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();